# Programmatically import FBX into asset file (custom editor)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm currently working on a custom editor in Unity3D, and I'd like to add some custom properties (and components) during the import process of assets.

The idea is to provide 3D designers a GUI where they can select an FBX file, fill in some additional properties, click on "import", and then a new asset would be created in the Unity project with the proper scripts already attached and set.

I've seen the `AssetPostprocessor` class that lets us do, well, some post processingh during import, but there doesn't seem to be a way to display a GUI from it.

I've also looked at the `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` method, but it only loads already imported assets.

So my question is, is there a way to display a GUI before the FBX file is imported (processed by) in Unity, and then create a unity asset (`.asset` file) by combining the data in the FBX file and the additional components (unity monobehavior scripts) I need to add?

Is it perhaps just not the way to go, and I will need using prefabs to achieve this? (I'd rather not, since prefabs seem to be useful as an aggregation of assets)

**EDIT**

The main goal is to make unity act as a level editor for level designers, and thus only have already half parameterized assets to deal with in the editor. This also means there are already many custom editors in the project.

Comment: You want a custom editor (make your own inspector) many assets use them, but you will have to create your own GUI, it just gives you access to the inspector window.

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan I'm not having trouble with custom editor at this point (I created some for this project already), it's about the importing process used in Unity, and how to plug into it

Comment: I think the only way to do anything with the fbx in unity is to import it and THAN process its mesh and change anything you want normally like you would do with any other mesh, and than save it back.

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan tried that, looking for an alternative way to do it since this means having duplicate models in the unity project: one with the additionnal properties added, and the original one. But perhaps there's just no other way to do it.....

Comment: Just use Editor script, pre-process it after the import and re-write the mesh

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan It's not just about the mesh, that's the thing. I'd really like to only have already half parameterized assets in the unity project for the level designers. But it would be a viable solution for the mesh though ;)

Comment: You can do everything else the same way with C# and any libraries that work with fbx files, for meshes unity has classes and methods ready, for everything else you use other frameworks (if unity doesnt have it already). For example I recall someone fixing Coordinate problems from blender to unity (axis were reversed left-handed right-handed), so he wrote an editor script which handeled it and made a GUI in unity for it.